# Ubuntu won't log in after update

Tags: updates, login

I just updated Ubuntu about 15 minutes ago on my desktop which is running 12.04. Within the set of updates, there were some kernel upgrades. It didn't say I needed to reboot after the update was finished, but I thought I would anyway.

The computer successfully rebooted up to the login screen. However, after entering my password, the screen goes black for a moment, then it comes back to the login screen.

I tried the suggestions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100423/ubuntu-wont-login), but unfortunately they didn't help. In the accepted answer, the questioner vaguely says it was a "Unity problem". I'm using Gnome-classic with full Compiz effects. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Compiz, but that didn't fix anything.

So... I can't use my desktop computer until this is fixed. I hope there is some help soon.

I've uploaded the [output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log` to Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1080687/).

A temporary solution of changing to gdm instead of lightdm was found with [help in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/bookmark-for-dave-m-g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody asked me that same question the other day :

> since yesterday my ubuntu 12.04 locks me out, i can only access the guest account.
>   if i enter the correct password for the admin account,
>    the screen turns black and then goes back to the log in screen.
>   if i enter an incorrect password, it says incorrect password.
>   if i create a new admin account via the guest account, i get the same problem.
>   resetting the password won't help :(
>   any ideas anyone?

It seem's a few people have had this problem, and using `gdm` instead of `lightdm` is the recommended workaround, and it worked for the person that asked me - after a couple of reboots. Have a look at these links for instructions & let me know if it helps.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen

[Can't log in to ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139528/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-12-04)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130721/12-04-lightdm-cannot-login

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I got some advice in chat that said basically the same thing, so it seems this is the way to go. I ran `sudo apt-get install gdm`, which brought up a dialog to select gdm instead of lightdm, and then it was possible to log in.

Comment: Glad it helped you too, and thanks for the feedback. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your graphics card is not supported or isn't updated anymore, or something is not supported/became corrupt in the update? Use alt+F2 to drop back to a console in the login screen, log in as root, see if you can: `sudo apt-get upgrade` + `sudo apt-get update` to see if that will correct something that needed correcting. It's not very likely, but it's worth a try.

Maybe try to re-install your graphics driver this way as well. Additionally, maybe you should try a package update or repair with GNOME in case the issue lies in the desktop-environment itself.

Lastly, maybe this link will help you out: [How To Fix Broken Packages In Ubuntu Or Debian](http://www.thepowerbase.com/2012/04/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu-or-debian/)

Hope you get this sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

The description alone is not enough for me to decide of the exact cause, but I can offer some help in diagnosing and fixing the problem.

First, you should be able to login into a text terminal without having to start your window manager.

Click CTRL-ALT-F1 to get access to one of your virtual terminals (to go back to graphical: usually CTRL-ALT-F7 should get you back into the graphical login screen gdm, kdm, or whatever you are using).  Once in a virtual terminal, you should be able to login and get a shell.

Once in, look at the logs, in particular your window-manager logs and the X11 logs under /var/logs/... to figure out the cause of the failure of your window manager.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I looked at /var/log/Xorg.log, but there were no errors in it at all. I dont know which other log files would be relevant, if any.

Comment: I think it should be /var/log/Xorg.0.log.  Also:  'ls -ltr /var/log' would show the most recently modified files under /var/log at the end of the list, so you can walk backward from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old thread, if anyone is having this problem and looking for a answer, see the link below where the same question was answered well with an easy fix.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-12-10-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

After you get a login screen, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log on. Then log on as root (you'll be asked for you password):

```
sudo su
```

Then try these commands one after another:

```
gdm stop

less /var/log/gdm/\:0-greeter.log

cd /var/lib/gdm/

mv .config/ .config-bkup

ls -ltr

service gdm stop

apt-get install gnome-session

apt-get indicator-applet-session

apt-get install indicator-applet-session

service gdm status

cd ~

mv .ICEauthority ICEauthority-bkup

{don't remove these file just backup}

mv .Xauthority Xauthority-bkup

service gdm start
```

Reboot is not necessary, if it asks for reboot:

```
init 5 / reboot
```